# Citroën C2 won't start

Tags: starting

Citroen c2 did start fine, but after changing cam belt it won't start.
It is cranking over, but not starting. Dash lights are on. Doesn't seem to get spark. Please Help?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the fact that you just changed the cam belt is significant in my mind.

1. Did you put the engine back together "in time"?  Are you sure?
2. Did you neglect to reconnect any electrical connectors, tubes, pipes, etc.?

Comment: Absolutely agree. @YolandiStrydom, don't crank it anymore until you make absolutely sure everything is aligned, you could be damaging your engine if it isn't.